# Causing a invalid day error when using the adhoc dates on the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am told to create a calendar-like list of dates based on existing records and to tell if a record exists on that date.

To have a sample scenario, take these records from a sample table: `TIME_LOG`(`ID`, `PUNCH_TIME`).

```
1   1/1/2018 8:00:00
2   1/1/2018 12:12:00
...
n   2/14/2020 8:00:00
```

In this example, what I need to do is to:

1. Get all the months present on the `TIME_LOG`, which are January 2018 and February 2020.
2. List all dates inside those two months, which are January 1 - 31, 2018 plus February 1 - 29, 2020. And then set it as column `DATE_TOKEN` of the result set.
3. Set `'Record found'` or `'No records found'` whether the value from `DATE_TOKEN` column exists from `TIME_LOG`. Make that as column `IS_FOUND` of the result set.

To retrieve that result set, this is my preliminary query:

```
SELECT   a.date_token,
         NVL2 (b.date_token, 'Record found.',
               'No records found.') AS is_found
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE (a.MONTH || '/' || b.DAY || '/' || a.YEAR,
                          'MM/DD/YYYY'
                         ) AS date_token
            FROM (SELECT   TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM a.punch_time)
                                   ) AS MONTH,
                           TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.punch_time)) AS YEAR
                      FROM vw_each_punch a
                  GROUP BY TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM a.punch_time)),
                           TO_CHAR (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.punch_time))) a
                 JOIN
                 (SELECT     TO_CHAR (ROWNUM) AS DAY
                        FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31) b
                 -- I placed this condition to eliminate dates such as February 31, etc.
                 -- and it works unless I uncomment the WHERE clause below.
                 ON b.DAY <=
                      EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (TO_DATE (   a.MONTH
                                                           || '/1/'
                                                           || a.YEAR,
                                                           'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                          )
                                                 )
                              )
                 ) a
         LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT   TRUNC (a.punch_time) AS date_token
              FROM vw_each_punch a
          GROUP BY TRUNC (a.punch_time)) b ON b.date_token = a.date_token
-- WHERE TRUNC (a.date_token, 'MONTH') = '1-FEB-2020'
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

This works fine and retrieves 60 rows on the resultset, similar to this (`DATE_TOKEN`, `IS_FOUND`):

```
1/1/2018    Record found.
1/2/2018    No records found.
1/3/2018    No records found.
...
2/13/2018   No records found.
2/14/2018   Record found.
2/15/2018   No records found.
...
```

until I needed to filter the resultset with certain months. When I try to uncomment the `WHERE` clause on my query to show only the dates on February 2020, it throws me an error:

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

The resultset loads completely without any errors as long as there are no `WHERE` clause, shown by the previous resultset with 60 rows. I suspect the error originates from the fact that February 2020 is less than 31 days, but that has been removed by `b.DAY <= EXTRACT (DAY FROM LAST_DAY (TO_DATE (a.MONTH || '/1/' || a.YEAR, 'MM/DD/YYYY')))` condition. Also, I changed the condition from February 2020 to January 2018 but it still doesn't work.

Is there any way I can use the `WHERE` clause without it throwing an `ORA-01839` error?

Here is a running SQL sample using subquery factoring if you need to run it ASAP:

```
WITH time_log_temp (id, punch_time) 
     AS (SELECT 1, 
                To_date('2018-1-1 8:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 2, 
                To_date('2018-1-1 12:12:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT 2, 
                To_date('2020-2-14 8:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') 
         FROM   dual), 
     inter 
     AS (SELECT a.date_token, 
                Nvl2 (b.date_token, 'Record found.', 'No records found.') AS 
                is_found 
         FROM   (SELECT To_date (a.month 
                                 || '/' 
                                 || b.day 
                                 || '/' 
                                 || a.year, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_token 
                 FROM   (SELECT To_char (Extract (month FROM a.punch_time)) AS 
                                MONTH, 
                                To_char (Extract (year FROM a.punch_time))  AS 
                                YEAR 
                         FROM   time_log_temp a 
                         GROUP  BY To_char (Extract (month FROM a.punch_time)), 
                                   To_char (Extract (year FROM a.punch_time))) a 
                        join (SELECT To_char (ROWNUM) AS DAY 
                              FROM   dual 
                              CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31) b 
                          -- I placed this condition to eliminate dates such as February 31, etc. 
                          -- and it works unless I uncomment the WHERE clause below. 
                          ON b.day <= Extract (day FROM Last_day ( 
                                                        To_date (a.month 
                                                                 || '/1/' 
                                                                 || a.year, 
                                                        'MM/DD/YYYY')))) a 
                left join (SELECT Trunc (a.punch_time) AS date_token 
                           FROM   time_log_temp a 
                           GROUP  BY Trunc (a.punch_time)) b 
                       ON b.date_token = a.date_token 
         ORDER  BY 1, 
                   2) 
SELECT * 
FROM   inter 
-- WHERE  Trunc(date_token, 'MONTH') = '1-JAN-2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting exactly that error from the filters you've shown, but fundamentally the problem is that you're comparing your (truncated) date with a string, which has to be implicitly converted to a date for the comparison. That relies on your NLS settings, specifically `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`; and that clearly don't match the string format.

You should change the filter to compare against a date instead:

```
WHERE  Trunc(date_token, 'MONTH') = to_date('1-FEB-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

... which is still relying on your `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting for the month name, or slightly better:

```
WHERE  Trunc(date_token, 'MONTH') = to_date('01-02-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

or better still, shorter and unambiguous, use an ANSI date literal:

```
WHERE  Trunc(date_token, 'MONTH') = DATE'2020-02-01'
```

Another approach that avoids having to truncate the date column (which may prevent an index being used in your real query) is to use a date range instead:

```
WHERE date_token >= DATE '2020-02-01' AND date_token < DATE'2020-03-01'
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, my fault that I forgot to mention that I already tried parsing the string to date but with no avail.